# Connecting to a java swing panel

Tags: java, swing

I have a JAVA application that, every five minutes, transfers  data from a Data Base A  to a Data Base B. Then, the application makes some calculations with the data of the Data Base B, and shows the results in a java swing panel.  The application is continuously running.  All ok.

I would like to see this java swing panel from other computers (more than one). So the idea is to see the panel from different computer whenever you want. I have thought  of making a webpage showing the results, but I have no idea of making webpages and I haven’t much time to deal with it.

Is it possible to make a fast java application (or anything else) that connects with my swing panel from another computer?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should either use a web page (maybe use an embedded webserver to do this) or provide an API (webservice, rpc etc.) for other applications to access the data. Directly "connecting" to a panel is neither easily possible nor does it make much sense. What you're after is a client (panel) - server (database connetivity and calculation) setup so you should implement it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an applet, your Swing components will be added to a JApplet instead of a JFrame, and any web client can download the full application. You will still need to make a web page, but it could only have your Java applet in it.